# hide navigationBar without removing the 20 height view

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

i've created below code which is hiding the statusBar when delegate Method is being executed. However my intention is just to hide the statusBar text and not remove the view behind the statusBar. Is there a way to keep the height of the navigationBar and statusBar with just hiding the text?

```
func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController!, willMoveToPosition position: FrontViewPosition) {
    if position == FrontViewPosition.Right {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation.Fade)
        println("lol")


    }
}

func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController!, didMoveToPosition position: FrontViewPosition) {
    if position == FrontViewPosition.Left {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation.Fade)



    }
}
```

Comment: no u can't hide the text.what u can do is create a `UIView` for 20 height an add it when u hide the status bar

Comment: okay where do i add it so it will push the navigationController down?

Comment: For this you may have to create navigation item and not navigation controller OR u can make UIView for height equivalent to navigation bar height